# npm install i18next-conv: Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'

Tags: node.js, installation, npm, i18next

I'm trying to install i18next-conv but, when I run `sudo npm install i18next-conv -g`, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
at require (module.js:375:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sha/index.js:3:48)
at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:359:17)

If you need help, you may report this log at:
<http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
or email it to:
<npm-@googlegroups.com>
System Darwin 11.4.2
command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "i18next-conv" "-g"
cwd /Users/personalcomputer/Desktop
node -v v0.6.18
npm -v 1.3.5

Additional logging details can be found in:
    /Users/personalcomputer/Desktop/npm-debug.log
not ok code undefined
not ok code 1
```

Can anyone tell me what can I do to install it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I had to do was update node version from node web page

Comment: Me too! That's embarrassing.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should be solved if you update node.js and possibly npm as well.

Note you can update npm with npm itself via the command:

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

Comment: Just tryed updating it, but I got the same error... How can I make npm to be accessible globally? (I think that's the problem)

Comment: By the looks at the error message it is accessible globally, otherwise you'd have permissions errors. It cannot find the 'readable-stream' module that is built into the node core so am assuming that the version of node is too old to support the operation. Glad to see you've fixed the problem though!