# Node.js cannot find module 'readable-stream'

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I am new to node.js and stuck on the following. Any help will be appreciated:

I am running node.js (0.10.28) on ubuntu (12.10). The code I am working on is:

```
"use strict";

var  mysql = require('node-mysql'),
connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "dbname"
});
    if(connection) { 
    console.log("Query");
    connection.query("select * from client",function(err,res) {
    if(err)console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
});
}
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/RonakNodeEmail/node_modules/node-mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:7:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [npm install i18next-conv: Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090548/npm-install-i18next-conv-error-cannot-find-module-readable-stream)

Comment: Have you made sure to install `readable-stream` through npm? `npm install readable-stream`

Answer (score 16):

I got this error for the a long while. Stupidly I hadn't installed gulp... In short this problem occurs when a package is missing.

```
npm install gulp -g
```

I would suggest working out which task you are running and then install that.

Comment: Solved my problem - 10x!

Comment: Had same problem, I personally needed to reinstall `node` and deleted `node_modules` folder. `npm install` again and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, (windows)
after uninstalling nodejs, and before reinstalling it
I had to delete the folder:

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

and after reinstalling node it worked like a sharm

Answer (score 5):

There were many reason for this issue: I have faced this issue because I had older version of node.js related files.

1. Un-install the node.js
2. Go to your user folder like `C:\Users\<uname>` and find all the node.js related files and delete everything.
3. Install node.js freshly

It worked for me.

Comment: I had also to delete the ```C:\Program Files\nodejs``` folder manually after uninstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem building a vue library. Deleting `node_modules` and re-running `npm isntall` and then rebuilding my lib worked.

Comment: This seamed to be the easiest solution so I tried it first and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

After grepping I found:

```
  $ cd /usr/lib/
  $ ack-grep readable-stream
nodejs/sha/index.js
3:var Transform = require('stream').Transform || require('readable-stream').Transform
```

and change that line to:

```
var Transform = require('stream').Transform // || require('readable-stream').Transform
```

and error goes out!

-- System Information: