# npm cannot find module

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I've been all over Google and StackOverflow, viewing the various threads related to similar issues, but so far nothing has worked. My problem is that npm seems to be installing improperly...or something, I honestly have no idea: Node and npm are a dependency I use to support the Sage Wordpress theme buildout I'm working on on a different machine.

So the issue is that after uninstalling Node (to be safe), and reinstalling, Node seems to be working fine. `node -v` returns `v5.1.0`. Great. npm should be installed with it, but when I run `npm -v` I get the following lovely bit of error:

```
    $ npm
    module.js:340
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
        at require (module.js:385:17)
        at Object.<anonymous>                 (/Users/Daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/        npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js:2:14)
        at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

Running any npm command (even just `npm`) gives me this error, so as suggested in other solutions, I cannot simply run `npm install readable-stream`. I have also gone through various solutions (removing the node_modules folder, installing via brew, installing via brew without npm, and several others), but none seem to be working.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `npm cache-clean` before reinstalling

Comment: @adeneo negative. Let me try again

Comment: Your answer in [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035106/npm-version-shows-error-cannot-find-module-readable-stream), you should research before post question.

Comment: @DinhNC Per my question, that does not work. I definitely saw that post and it did not solve my issue.

Comment: Have you ever runned this line "npm install gulp -g"?

Comment: @DinhNC Again, per my post, running `npm` alone or with any combination of arguments following gives me that error.

Comment: Then you somehow have to manually update npm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're having problems with NPM and you want to reinstall on UNIX I found this to be the easiest solution:

`curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

This will reinstall NPM and get it setup to use the latest NPM Version. This will almost always resolve any issues regarding NPM.

When the process is complete you should receive a message saying `It worked`.

Comment: What exactly is this doing? When I run that line (copy/pasted into the terminal), I get the following output: `  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193  100   193    0     0    305      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   305
sh: line 1: html: No such file or directory
sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'h: line 2: `<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>`

Comment: This will go to NPM and and install the latest version from their site. Make sure you have the `-L` flag when calling `curl`, that will follow the 301 redirect.

Comment: So, is it possible that they have a syntax error in their code? Also, it seems there may be a 301 issue as well...

Comment: updated my answer, to prevent any permissions issues, add `sudo` before the call to `sh`

Comment: Well, I'm either an idiot, or I ran some other variation of this code that did not work. I DID reinstall npm in similar fashion several times, but using your snippet solved this for me. Thanks for bearing with me!

Answer (score 5):

I was just wrestling with this problem for half an hour (on Mac) after a failed npm update. I'm using Homebrew and I found I had to do the following:

`sudo chown -Rv $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules/` with my username

Then I reinstalled node via Homebrew:

`brew uninstall node`

`brew install node`

By this point `npm` was working again and I went ahead with a successful `npm i -g npm`

Answer (score 0):

You can run with command line as below:

```
npm install // you need remove node_modules folder, run npm install
```

Comment: Perhaps you are using Mac OS? You run with line "rm -rf node_modules" => "rm -rf ~/.npm" => "npm install"

Comment: Sometimes, after fully removing npm and reinstalling node its working again

Comment: Yes, I am on OSX, but removing the node_modules folder and reinstalling has not been working.