# Error Installing Cordova on Node Js

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, npm, npm-install

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.3.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\ATULQU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-948-67415186\registry.npmjs.org\npm\-\npm-2.15.1.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 1232b36de78a2129a7c91f69e47abb8f093308c2
npm ERR! Actual:   4367d007fab244d37e00b0a85424d28f8f33d04e
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.15.1.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Using node for the first time. Getting the following error while install Cordova "npm install -g cordova".

Using Git on windows 8

Comment: Try updating your `npm`, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778667/npm-cannot-find-module/35779242#35779242)

Comment: Its already the latest version ! v4.3.2

Comment: No, your `node` version is 4.3.2 and thats not even the newest, 5.9.0 is the newest. Your `npm` is 2.14.12, `npm` is up to 3.8.2 and the jump from v2 to v3 is quite drastic.