# npm --version is giving errormodule.js:538 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

After installation of Node.js,i checked the version of node by typing in cmd:

> node --version,

it showed me the version,but when I type

> npm --version

it gives me an error

```
module.js:538 
     throw err;
     ^
Error: Cannot find module
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778667/npm-cannot-find-module

Comment: its giving the same problem

Comment: hey finally got the solution...

Comment: In Environmental variable there are two variable so in user variable "Path" should only consist C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: And in System variable "Path" should consist only C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Comment: keep both them on top

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error when run the angular 4 project.

**module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'**

To fix the error, just run..

```
npm i -D @angular-devkit/core
```

also check in package.json folder, ^ symbol added in "@angular/cli":"^1.6.1",

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.4.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.1",
```