# Cannot find module 'readable-stream' when using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed nodejs and am trying to use npm on my Windows machine. I downloaded all the files from [nodejs website](https://nodejs.org/en/).  I tried to install the latest `4.4.2` version or `5.10.1` version, but I always got error `Cannot find module 'readable-stream'` when I tried to run commands using `npm`.

```
C:\Users\Ealon>node -v                                                             
v5.10.1                                                                             

C:\Users\Ealon>npm -v                                                              
module.js:341                                                                       
    throw err;                                                                      
    ^                                                                                                                                                                   
Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'                                         
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)                          
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)                                     
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)                                            
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)                                           
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ealon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node
modules\npmlog\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\index.js:2:14)                         
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)                                           
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)                             
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)                                               
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)                                     
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

I tried to reinstall it again and again, still could not fix this problem. And the answers in another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010598/node-js-cannot-find-module-readable-stream) do not help because I always got error when I tried to run **any command using `npm`**. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `npm` appears to require [readable-stream](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/db9cde008ce855bdac801bb6649cbfb5bb7911ac/package.json#L85). Do you have a `readable-stream` folder in your npm folder? (probably located at `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`, or a path similar)

Comment: @dvlsg Yes, I have it...

Comment: That is very odd. Good to rule that out, at least, though. Do you have any previous versions of `npm` installed? Possibly globally? You can type `where npm` from the command line to figure out if you have any additional installs / references in your path. I can see that its referencing `%appdata%\npm` in one of the errors, which I believe is where global installs go.

Comment: @dvlsg Thanks for your help. I somehow fixed this issue by upgrading `npm` in Intellij IDEA. But I still don't know why this issue happened. :(

Comment: I still feel like it was a weird global install. It looks like the `are-we-there-yet` module inside of a global `npm` install also needed a reference to `readable-stream`, so it's possible that *that* reference was missing. Hard to say. I'd be tempted to wipe out any install of `npm` in `%appdata%`, if there's still one there.

Comment: @dvlsg I think your explanation makes sense. If possible, can you post an answer about this so that I can accept that as I don't want to accept my own answer. Thanks!

Comment: I *can*, but even I'm not convinced it's the actual answer, haha. Hard to say, since it's fixed. Glad it's working, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the line `C:\Users\Ealon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node
modules\npmlog\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\index.js:2:14` in the stack trace, I believe that you had a global installation of `npm` which internally had a dependency on `are-we-there-yet`, which I confirmed has a dependency on `readable-stream`.

The global installation of `npm` appears to have been borked, and `are-we-there-yet` couldn't resolve access to the `readable-stream` module for some reason (bad install?).

This wasn't getting fixed by re-installing `node`, which by default installs `npm` into program files (path similar to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm`). I think the global version was getting run, but the version inside program files *should* be getting run, so wiping out the global installation of `npm` should hopefully resolve the issue.

Comment: I installed latest node and landed into exactly same problem and got it working by using exactly same solution - wipe the global installation of npm. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I somehow fixed this issue by upgrading `npm` in Intellij IDEA.

[image]

But I still want an expnalation why that problem in my question happened. I will not mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to uninstall node js. When I tried to update my node version, I got this issue & resolved the the same by following below step -

> Go to control panel --> uninstall Programs --> select node.js

and click repair.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue on a Mac. I cloned a project multiple times to handle different branches in parallel. Only one of my cloned repos started having this same issue when I ran `npm start`. I deleted the repo, cloned it again and nom was running fine again in that repo. Doesn't sound like a global issue to me. No idea what went wrong.