# Error while running npm & unable to install npm on Homestead

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, homestead

I receive this error while running whatever command with npm:

```
npm install

npm -v
```

etc.

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\index.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

### Update

I have solved this issue on Windows by deleting npm folder in c://user/USER/appdata/roaming/npm.

However, npm is no longer working on Homestead and error message displayed when I attempted to install npm.

```
vagrant@homestead:~/webapp/site$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be inst                                                                                        alled
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Its look like you are not imported `readable-stream` in the context where it is used

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010598/node-js-cannot-find-module-readable-stream

Comment: the error message above appears whenever npm command is used.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows link and install it again.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error , after new update of nodejs installed in my computer .

use this trick you say about that :

**I have solved this issue on Windows by deleting npm folder in c://user/USER/appdata/roaming/npm.**

and delete nodejs folder in programFiles

and then reinstall nodejs . and it solved for me